# Set-contains or intersection in msbuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild

In the following MSBuild fragment, I'm trying to make an ItemGroup which contains a subset of the referenced assemblies -- so that if LibA or LibB are referenced, then they're contained in the output item, but if they're not referenced, then they're not included (and it will never include any items other than the ones specified).

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RefSubset Include="@(ReferencePath)"
               Condition="'%(ReferencePath.Filename)' == 'LibA' OR
                          '%(ReferencePath.Filename)' == 'LibB'"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works, but it seems inelegant.  What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RefSubsetNames>LibA;LibB</RefSubsetNames>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then rewrite the `RefSubset` rule in such a way that it uses `RefSubsetNames` to perform the condition.

Important goals:

- All metadata on `ReferencePath` must be preserved into `RefSubset`.
- `RefSubsetNames` could contain empty values (`;;`) which must be ignored.
- Each component of `RefSubsetNames` should do an exact match on the `ReferencePath.Filename` -- it should not allow subset matches (so basic `Contains` checks are wrong).

I've managed to achieve what I want with this, but it seems a bit ugly and I was wondering if there was a better solution?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <RefSubset Include="@(ReferencePath)"
               Condition="$([System.String]::Copy(';$(RefSubsetNames);').Contains(';%(ReferencePath.Filename);'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: The code at the end of my question does work, it's just a bit uglier than I would have liked.

Comment: It is possible to apply the ideas from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403046/msbuild-itemgroup-intersection
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/msbuild/batching-brainteaser-explained
to do it "right" (by comparing metadata for equality instead of 'Contains'), but the code will be much more, while your idea to surround with ; seems good enough in practice and much more compact.